# Fullcalendar shows events 1 hour ahead

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I got JSON with correct time but fullcalendar (?) shows my event 1 hour ahead.  I tried timezone : local , ignoreTimezone but no success any help would be nice I'm desprate.

My timezone is `UTC +08:00`
My json is `{"hmi_alldays":[{""order_employee_start":"2015-02-03T05:00:00","order_id":1791}`

Comment: I suspect you are on the right lines but it might be daylight savings time that is affecting your dates.  What timezone are you in? Does the local area use daylight savings time? And if so, are you currently in DST?

Comment: Thanks for adding the json.  So is `2015-02-03T05:00:00` the correct time or the time 1 hour ahead?

Comment: Its correct time but in my calendar it shows 06:00 not 05:00

Comment: Well, unless you are going to provide some code that takes the json and converts it to displayed output in your calendar, we aren't going to be able to help any further.  It is at that stage where your issue lies.  Also, my questions about DST still need an answer.  Thanks.

Comment: How do you feed the JSON into the calendar? Btw. your JSON cannot be valid there are too many quotes at the beginning of `order_employee_start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I don't know which version of fullcalendar you are using, but the latest version at this time (2.2.6) in combination with moment.js and the usage of timezone works completely fine for me:

```
var events_array = [
    {
    title: 'Test1',
    start: moment('2015-02-03T05:00:00'),
    end : moment('2015-02-03T12'),
    tip: 'Test1'},
];
...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events_array,
    timezone : 'local',
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.attr('title', event.tip);
    }
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oo4t7fzy/1/).